# Microsoft Visual Studio Cordova Tools dosn't build Application

Tags: node.js, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I use Cordova Tools for Visual Studio 2013.4.
When I try to build the application Output is:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: AppName, Configuration: Debug Android ------  
1>  GeneratedJavascript=scripts\index.js;scripts\index.js.map;scripts\platformOverrides.js;scripts\platformOverrides.js.map  
1>  D:\AppFolder\AppFolder\AppName>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat  
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.26 (ia32) and npm.  
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\V4YXQHUD.HVK\packages\vs-mda
```

and it stops, not get built:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried a blank Application?  When you installed the Tools did you take all the default settings?

Comment: yes, all default settings.

Comment: Try to remove and reinstall Visual Studio.  It seems like something did not install correctly.

Comment: I did it, but no luck. I tried to reinstalling VS, Update3 with CTP2 and also Update4 with CTP3. finally I reinstalled my windows, installed vs2013, installed Update4, and installed CTP3, then I clear Cordova cache and build and wait for all cordova assets to download.
Then it my problem got solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(SOLVED)

I tried to reinstalling VS, Update3 with CTP2 and also Update4 with CTP3. finally I reinstalled my windows, installed vs2013, installed Update4, and installed CTP3, then I clear Cordova cache and build and wait for all cordova assets to download.
Then it my problem got solved.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the Apache Cordova Cache will also fix this problem. Note that when you Build your App the FIRST time after clearing the Cordova Cache, you will need Internet Access since the process downloads files into the cache.

[image: Clearing the Apache Cordova Cache will also fix this problem]

Comment: I tried this one at first, after downloading all files, the problem was exist yet.